# How can I make to get friends list android app on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to create get freinds list and unfriend finder feature in android app.
I use facebook sdk or etc...

Do I need to be authenticated to use the feature?
And can I find examples with these features?

Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Get Friends list is based on the user profile. if the user friends list show in public profile they only get the friend slist

Comment: @Raj When I use the Android sdk, how do I know the parameters of a friend list? I want to compare my old friend list with my new friend list in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook SDK new version disable "Get friend list" api. U just can get list of friend who use ur application.
You can research about graph api here to know which parameter to pass: [Document for graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph)

[Test graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/)

And you have to provide login facebook function to use these api

Comment: Thank you for your help! :-)